# Angular controllers and directives getting values from controller into directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, angular-controller

I have a directive in my angular website that builds a page header, in that page header I am wanting to show the user's first and last name. I am wrapping my entire application in a MainController. My rendered HTML looks like this,

```
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as main" class="fa-events-icons-failed ng-scope">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}.ng-animate-shim{visibility:hidden;}.ng-anchor{position:absolute;}</style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title ng-bind="main.windowTitle" class="ng-binding">App School Management</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/css/generic.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/css/styles.min.css">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/2a6c262d81.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.fontawesome.com:443/js/stats.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/2a6c262d81.css" media="all">
</head>
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
    <div id="page-wrapper">
    <div id="page-header" class="bg-gradient-9 ng-isolate-scope" header="" user="userModel">
    <div id="mobile-navigation">
        <button id="nav-toggle" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#page-sidebar"><span></span></button>
        <a href="index.html" class="logo-content-small" title="MonarchUI"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="header-logo" class="logo-bg">
        <a ui-sref="dashboard.home" class="branding" title="Schoozle">
        App Logo
        </a>
        <a id="close-sidebar" href="#" title="Close sidebar">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="header-nav-left">
        <div class="user-account-btn dropdown">
            <a href="#" title="My Account" class="user-profile clearfix" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <img width="28" src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="Profile image">
            <span ng-bind="$scope.user.first_name" class="ng-binding"></span>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- #header-nav-left -->
    <div id="header-nav-right">
        <div class="dropdown" id="notifications-btn">
            <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" title="">
            <span class="small-badge bg-yellow"></span>
            <i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu box-md float-right">
                <!-- Notifications Dropdown -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My non directive HTML looks like this,

```
<div header user="userModel"></div>
```

And my controller code, and directive code looks this,

```
app.directive('header', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A', //This menas that it will be used as an attribute and NOT as an element. I don't like creating custom HTML elements
    replace: true,
    scope: {user: '='}, // This is one of the cool things :). Will be explained in post.
    templateUrl: "/templates/partials/header.html",
    controller: ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter) {
        // Your behaviour goes here :)
    }]
}
```

}]);

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'UserService', function($scope, UserService){
var self = this;

this.windowTitle = "App School Management";
this.loading = true;
this.user = {};

UserService.authenticatedUser()
    .then(function(response){
        self.loading = false;
        self.userModel = response.message;
    }, function(error) {
        self.hasError = true;
        self.errors = error.message;
    });
```

}]);

How do I get my user object from the controller into the directive?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `MainController as main`, add *main* to your directive:

```
<div header user="main.userModel"></div>
```

than user data will be available through your isolated scope two way binding within your 'templates/partials/header.html' as `user` object, something like `user.firstName` and `user.lastName`.

You can avoid using `$scope` by adding to your directive definition

```
controllerAs: 'ctrl';
bindToController: true;
```

than your user data will be available witin HTML as `ctrl.user` object